# Django Admin - django-smart-selects OR Many to Many dynamic filtering with Foreign Keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

Would like to ask how to achieve dynamic filtering in Admin. I know how to use django-smart-selects in admin but it works I guess only for FK not for many-to-many models.

I would like to achieve when I create an ART in the admin and select category it would filter only those artists which belong to that category & additionally when I select artist while creating Art it would filter those collections that belong to that Artist.

I can make Artists & Collections to work with django-smart-selects but artists & categories not because they are many-to-many.

Please help. Thanks

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Artist(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Collection(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Art(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `django-smart-selects` work with `ManyToMany` relationships https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-manytomany-selects I don't know if this be useful for you, taking into account the chaining  that you want.

Comment: Wonderful I was waiting when ManyToMany will be available. Thank you.